# Changing the timestamp of magic columns (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I want to change the default timestamp of the magic columns of rails (created_at, modified_at) instead of 2010-09-03 14:52:46 UTC I'd like to change it to September 10, 2010 at 02:52 PM. or at least parse that way.

Now, i know that i can do this right in the view, by manipulating the variable, but isnt there a more "railish way" where i can just do this in the model, and then call it as a method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def my_formated_date_time
    created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y at %I:%M %p")
  end
end
```

Or you can use the localization format. Add this to your `config/locale/your_locale.yml`. IMHO: This would be the most *railish* way.

```
your_locale:
  time:
    formats:
      default: "%B %d, %Y at %I:%M %p"
```

Then in your view do this

```
<%=l @your_model.created_at %>
<!-- short for: -->
<%= I18n.localize @your_model.created_at %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the `created_at` date is fine, it will stay as you set it, and you can over-ride it even at the start, but `updated_at` or `modified_at` might prove tricky. Every time you save your model this is changed. If you don't want this behavior, convention suggests switching to a different name.

If you want to adjust how dates are displayed, you need to configure the default formatter.